# Unity2D layering multiple canvas'

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I have two canvas' set up for my project, one to act as a background and one to hold foreground UI elements. Originally they were set to world space, and I had no problems, but now I am optimizing my game, I must change the space so they adjust to mobile phones. How can I design the canvas' so that one acts in the background and the other in the foreground? I have tried changing the z-pos and other quick fixes I found online but none have worked.

Comment: If you set the canvas render mode to Screen space - overlay, there will be a number named Sort order. Greater value brings elements to front, lesser sends them to back.

Comment: Tried this, didn't seem to work for me unless the sort order can't be less than one? Didn't give an error though.

Comment: I checked it and all values are working as expected, even below zero. How it's not working, gives wrong order of elements? Can you please add a screenshots of canvases and what you expect from them? And I forgot to say, overlay canvases always are over the world and sprites, if background is on canvas it will cover them, maybe this is your problem.

Comment: My problem is that I need the canvas behind the sprites and other gameobjects ect. is there anyway to do this without using the world canvas?

Comment: If your background is a single image, you can use a sprite

Comment: My background is a text UI that need changing, and needs to be behind all sprites.

Comment: You can set canvas render mode to Screen space - camera, add another camera to scene for it, configure culling masks of your cameras, probably adding a layer for background UI, configure camera depth, and then set main camera clear mode to Dont clear. I see no solution other than this.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can use the [sorting Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-sortingOrder.html) for that .. afaik smaller values are drawn first, bigger values are drawn on top. Or maybe [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-determines-canvas-render-order.266682/) helps

Comment: @derHugo I believe that only orders the canvas', But I need it ordered lower then the sprites too.

Comment: @trollingchar can you explain this a bit more? I am struggling to follow. Thank you!

Comment: @Mattattack I don't follow you ... I thought you are looking for how to sort two canvas .. one foreground and one background canvas?

Comment: @Mattattack, I've created a chat room where we can discuss your problem rather than in comments, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184307/chat-with-mattattack-about-canvases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have background canvas, sprites and foreground canvas, and background canvas should be behind everything including sprites.

The idea is to render at first only background with one camera, and then render everything with another.

To do that, we should:

- **Add a layer for background canvas. Change layer of background canvas and children to that layer.**

To add a layer, select any gameObject and in top of the inspector you will see:

[image]

Click on a dropdown list labeled "Layer" and select "Add Layer". Then create new layer and give it a name:

[image]

Select your background canvas and change layer for it and its children. **When adding gameObjects, keep in mind that if you add them to background canvas, their layer must be the same as the layer of canvas, otherwise they will be rendered by the wrong camera**.

- **Disable that layer in main camera's culling mask.**

Now the camera should no longer render background UI, and it will disappear in the game view.

- **Add a camera for rendering background UI.**

Cameras with higher depth render on top of those with lower depth, so we should **set its depth to less than depth of main camera**. We should also **set its culling mask to only layer for background UI**, otherwise all objects on scene will be rendered twice. **Copy other setting from main camera**. **Set main camera's clear mode to Don't Clear or Depth Only** to prevent it from erasing background.

- **Set mode of the background canvas to Screen Space - Camera and drag newly created camera into field "Render Camera" there.**

It should work now.